# website contact form issue concerning outlook office365 and digital ocean

Tags: php, smtp, digital-ocean, contact-form

I have a problem that i've been trying to figure out, but can't seem to fix. Perhaps someone here has had this problem before and knows a solution.

Problem:
Recently noticed the contact form on my website does not work reliably. The issue is, sometimes the form submits successfully, and sometimes not at all. When the forms are not successful, there is an error page displayed but does not list any error information so difficult to know what the problem is. It has been like this for over a month now.

Situation:
Prior to the above, there were no changes, updates or edits to the website, server or email app and all form submissions from the website were 100% successful. The website is hosted on digital ocean. We use outlook office365 for receiving form submissions from the website.

What we've tried so far:
We have set up a temp sendgrid account and used smtp settings from this 3rd party to send contact form from website. This seemed to resolve the problem.

**BUT! We would prefer to continue to use outlook office 365 instead of setting up with another 3rd party.**

Likely cause of problem:
So it seems, the issue probably has something to do with smtp settings for outlook office365. We've checked our settings, and everything is as it should. If it wasn't then we wouldn't be receiving any forms summited from the website at all. We are able to receive some form submissions and not others. You can test it out on our website contact page to see exactly what I mean.

https://www.miscea.com/en/contact

We've tried adding the website IP to the SPF records in the DNS.
We also tried adding website IP to Office 365 IP allow list.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of problem specifically with outlook office 365 and digital ocean? If more information needed, let me know.

~ Khanh